# How show authorized pdf from url in Android and not download it?

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-intent, authorization

I wrote some code for authorize pdf and show it by ACTION_VIEW.

```
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf));
    browserIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(pdf), "application/pdf");
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    browserIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Pdf is trying to open but in the end showing toast "Problem with file". I can open it in browser but browser allow only for download. This pdf it should be opened without downloading.

My question is: How I should properly show pdf which need bearer authorization and shouldn't be downloaded?

Comment: If you do not want to download it, then it cannot be viewed as a PDF. You would need to create some server-side conversion of the PDF into HTML and images or something.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, so in other way. How open it without going to browser and clicking to download file which is saved in DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS?

Comment: You can download the PDF file yourself using your favorite HTTP client API, such as OkHttp.